# Starting a new Activity with Spinner

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner, new-operator, status

I was wondering if anybody knows how to start a new activity, when you change the value of a spinner without having to press an button. 
I have been searching the web for hours, but I cannot find anything that leads me in the right direction. So i am hoping somebody here can help me.

This is just my code of a standard spinner:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share);

    Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.TUTORIAL1"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Loading...");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hourglass);

            dialog.show();
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.MENU"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                }
            });
            th.start();
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnerfood,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Bad UI design. No one expects a spinner to launch an activity. Controls are meant to be fiddled with. Don't you hate it on Web pages when they trigger page navigation upon a checkbox click?

Comment: its a order by spinner so it loads the connected api with a different variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `setOnItemSelectedListener`,,,,if select something `onItemSelected` is called ,else `onNothingSelected` is called

```
 s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                 String str = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();

                             //here print selected value...
                 System.out.println("String is :: " + str);

                             //And StartActivity here...

                    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: so my spinner says Newest and Ratings and Views, so where should i put those?

Comment: hmmm. ques im too noob for android development

Comment: would you mind show me an simple example about using setOnItemSelected() method?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=spinner+in+android+example+&oq=spinner+in+android+example+&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l4.167l6703l0l6751l15l12l1l0l0l2l938l4392l5-4j2l6l0.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=917db3fff837333b&biw=1280&bih=921

Comment: o nevermind already got it too work, was really simple thanks